# How to make a scrollbar with html5 canvas and perhaps JQuery Tools?

Tags: jquery, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to make a web thermometer like this (this is a drawing of my idea)[image: A drawing of my idea]

I was able to draw the body of the thermometer with Html5 canvas, but it's all static - I cannot interact with it. I need two text boxes that are editable, more importantly I need a scrollbar-like control in the center so that when the user drag it, the numbers in the text boxes will change.

What would be the simplest way to do that?

I know that JQuery Tools offers [ready-made range inputs](http://jquerytools.org/demos/rangeinput/vertical.html), which is quite similar to what I need because those range inputs come with text boxes. But is this the right way to go? I tried with the Jquery Tools range input but failed to incorporate it with my canvas. Moreover, I don't know whether it would be possible to add an extra text box to the range input.

Comment: Everything except the red circle at the end is easy to make without canvas. I mean, as far as interacting with the thermometer goes, if you would not enable dragging all the way to the circle ( it would always stay red ), you could totally do this without canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the css of the plugin you mentioned and make it visible exactly you have in the above pic..

Comment: you mean put the scrollbar in the center so that it looks like the same thing but it's actually a transparent scrollbar on top of a canvas right? If that's that case, I am worried that the page may suffer from cross-browser problems. Will it?

Comment: m not sure about the cross-browser problem for this...but that plugin is basically a simple scrollbar with css. You can get css for every browser...

Comment: Yes the scrollbar solution worked fine. I was able to adjust its css style and align it in the center. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

a little bit of sudo code

onmouseclick(target = thermomoterGrippie)
   {
    this.grippie = active
   }

onmousemove(event)
 {

}

once you can change the size of the RED. then you can make a little algorithym that calculates the tempreture depending on the red size